# Convert string to datetime Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

How can i convert String like 20100102 into datetime in a formate of dd/MM/yyyy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var userdateformat = DateTime.ParseExact("20101020", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Modify as you want to modify.

Answer (score 9):

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-EN", false); // use your culture info
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTimeString, "yyyyMMdd", culture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

yyyyMMdd is input format here.

And then if you wish convert it to string:

```
String output = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);
```

Comment: Right - except that it probably makes sense either to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` dependening on the scenario.

Comment: I changed user override to false. So it uses default now. But it will not cause any problems here even it overrides. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 9):

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("20100102", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Modify as needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method

Answer (score -3):

```
string strStartDateMain = "20100102";
string strStartDateFinal = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32strStartDateMain.Substring(0, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(strStartDateMain.Substring(4, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(strStartDateMain.Substring(6))).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: I got this answer by doing R&D on that topic.
Here If we have a string like "20100102", Than we can get output like
"02/01/2010"

Comment: Bah, this really isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Custom date parsing FTL.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Indeed, this isn't the right way to do it. This will give somewhat cryptic error messages if the format isn't quite right, or if the string is too short.

Comment: This is only used whene our strStartDateMain will comes in a same range and length.

Comment: he is just tried. for own question. so dont give him minus point. just leave comment. and tell him better way.