# how do i convert string to datetime in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert string to datetime Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989342/convert-string-to-datetime-using-c)
>   [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Hi,
I have a string which consists of datetime in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms

i.e. date/month/year hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds. eg. 18/03/2011 15:16:57.487

How do I convert this string to datetime using c#

Regards
cmrhema.

Comment: You *did* notice the *Related Questions* list that appeared when writing your question? There were plenty of exact duplicates of your question right there.

Comment: Before posting why don't you search for the previous post that are listed while posting the question

Comment: Searching again, I found this to be better (since it also points out `DateTime.TryParse`): [Convert string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c/1592660#1592660)

Comment: I swear there needs to be a DateTime.ParseExact tag, as this question comes up almost daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to parse in the format that your DateTime is in and also maintain the milliseconds

```
        string dtString = "18/03/2011 15:16:57.487";

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");           

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dtString.Split('.')[0], culture);

        Double milliseconds = Double.Parse(dtString.Split('.')[1]);

        dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

Comment: Wes Grant, I was looking for the above answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact

```
  DateTime dateValue;
  string dateString = "2/16/2008 12:15:12 PM";
  try {
     dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
  }   
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString);
  }
```

For ParseExact

```
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
try 
{
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "18/03/2011 15:16:57.487", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

Note that `MM` means month, `mm` means minute, `HH` is 24-hour hour, `hh` is 12-hour hour, and `f` is millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) is what you want if you know the exact format of the date string.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToDateTime()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="04031985";

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(str);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, @"MMddyyyy", null);
```