# Convert a string to custom DateTime

Tags: .net, string, datetime, .net-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to datetime Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989342/convert-string-to-datetime-using-c-sharp)

I want to convert string to DateTime in `.NET 2.0`. For example, the string will be in the format like `10/07/2011 (dd/MM/yyyy)` and then I want to convert it to DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse custom string date formats into a DateTime using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).
For example:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "10/07/2011",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can specify a culture that has a DMY date format, such as the UK:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("13/07/2011", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strdate);
```

Comment: Thanks but i got error as "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"